# Visual Studio does not recognize Python keywords anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on Azure functions that are written in Python, but when I open them use Visual Studio code I get a strange visualization (see [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRrgV.png)).

Everything looks fine until line 7 and from line 9 to 14, but on line 8 and from line 15 the IDE does not recognize keywords such as "with", and misses the first single quotation mark, therefore everything that is supposed to be between quotation marks is reversed. If I add an additional quotation mark to change this, it has no effect.

Two questions here:
1/ Does this affect the execution of the code? If the IDE does not recognize something well, maybe the compiler can experience similar issues?
2/ Is there a way to correct this issue, as this is pretty uncomfortable to work with?

Just to mention, other python files still work fine in VSCode.

Comment: try to close and reopen the file

Comment: I did but no luck with this method. Same if I restart VSCode or my laptop

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a theme extension suitable for me and it's fine now.
You can try too.
[I like and recommend this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6koXy.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).